# CPR cross-compile: No such file or directory error

Tags: c++, cmake, cross-platform, cross-compiling, clang++

I'm trying to compile cpr for android and run the sample project, but it gives an error when i run it on my 64 bit phone.
`/system/bin/sh: ./AndroidProject3: No such file or directory`

https://github.com/libcpr/cpr

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.22)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Android)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_VERSION 29)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm64-v8a)
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_NDK "/home/coret/android-ndk/")
set(CMAKE_ANDROID_STL_TYPE c++_static)
set(CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE "/home/coret/android-ndk/build/cmake/android.toolchain.cmake")
project(AndroidProject3)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(cpr GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/libcpr/cpr.git
                         GIT_TAG beb9e98806bb84bcc130a2cebfbcbbc6ce62b335) # The commit hash for 1.7.2. Replace with the latest from: https://github.com/libcpr/cpr/releases
FetchContent_MakeAvailable(cpr)


add_executable(AndroidProject3 main.cpp)
target_link_libraries(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE cpr::cpr -static)
```

```c
#include <cpr/cpr.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    cpr::Response r = cpr::Get(cpr::Url{"https://api.github.com/repos/whoshuu/cpr/contributors"},
                      cpr::Authentication{"user", "pass"},
                      cpr::Parameters{{"anon", "true"}, {"key", "value"}});
    r.status_code;                  // 200
    r.header["content-type"];       // application/json; charset=utf-8
    r.text;                         // JSON text string
    return 0;
}
```

How do I solve it?

Comment: "... but it gives an error" - **When** you got this error? Do you get it when you **build** the project? Or do you get it when you **run** the resulted executable? Please, add more details into the question post. See also [ask].

Comment: @Tsyvarev "/system/bin/sh: ./AndroidProject3: No such file or directory" when i run it on my phone(arm64-v8a) i get this error.